# Qt sscanf equivalent

Tags: c++, qt

Say I have this:

```
QString mystring = "67 49 213 59";
int a, b, c, d;
```

Is there a Qt alternative to sscanf so I can read the numbers into the `int` variables?

Comment: Assuming you can use Boost, there is such a thing as lexical cast, that well you convert strings to ints, or other number formats. It will require you to break your string into the separate values, but that shouldn't be too hard

Comment: I just don't want to mix Qt code with boost, stdio, or std. The styles are totally different, and besides, Qt is a fairly complete library. I think it is generally able to replace the C and C++ runtime completely in terms of functionality.

Comment: What do you need it for? You can convert QString to a C string, using for instance QString::toLocal8Bit() and feed it to sscanf?

Comment: @thecoshman Can you elaborate?

Comment: @satuon you stubbornly sticking to only what has been wrapped up by qt is idiotic

Comment: I agree with satuon : Qt has a fairly big list of features (So far, I didn't find something which I couldn't solve with the qtlib which would boost solve for me) and there is no reason to mix it with boost which would bloat your application with another framework (especially if you develop for an embedded device..). So I would not call it "idiotic"...

Comment: @TWE: Then why use `int`? That's not provided by Qt. Are you aware that Boost is not a "framework"? And `lexical_cast` is header-only? i.e. **no bloat!** We use it on embedded devices _just fine_.

Comment: To be fair int is a fundamental type that is used extensively in Qt, for example as return type for many calls. And some people (me included) define bloat to include complex dependencies such as boost even if they are "header only".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`QTextStream`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextstream.html) provides the equivalent of the standard library's streams.
Don't forget that the text stream should be destroyed *before* the string.

```
QString mystring = "67 49 213 59";
QTextStream myteststream(&mystring);
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0;
myteststream >> a >> b >> c >> d;
```

Comment: +1: Though it might be worth making more of a point that this is an equivalent to iostreams, not to `sscanf`.

Answer (score 5):

```
int a, b, c, d;
QString s("67 49 213 59");
QTextStream(&s) >> a >> b >> c >> d;
```

Comment: You can't take the address of a temporary the way you're doing in your first example.  If your compiler allows it, it shouldn't.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley: yes, I added the correct syntax in the bottom part. GCC signal the error, and warn about a -fstrict. But I didn't tried if that allows to accept the syntax. Should I delete that first line?

Answer (score 1):

```
QString str("67 49 213 59");
QStringList list = str.split(" ");
int a[list.count];
for (int i = 0; i < list.count; i++)
   a[i] = list[i].toInt();
```

Comment: Some explanation could be helpful

Comment: To me this seems like clean sample code and answer to the question. The code is straightforward and simple.

Comment: The only reason this compiles is because you're using a non-standard C++ extension.

Answer (score 1):

You could always just do

```
QByteArray oString = mystring.toAscii();
const char *pszString = oString.constData();
```

and then use sscanf() as normal.